# Hiding BigCommerce cart wording with javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bigcommerce

I've installed a badge icon that I would like to show the number of items in the shopping cart.

The problem is that it's for a BigCommerce site and the way the cart count is displayed is "View Cart" along with the number of items in the cart.

I was told there might be a way to hide the "View Cart" portion with javascript or jQuery so I would be able to display the number only. I have no idea how I would do this so would appreciate ideas.

I've attached two screeshots. The first is how it displays currently. The second is how I would like it to display. Also added my code at the bottom. %%GLOBAL_CartItems%% is the BigCommerce global variable that generates the cart count as shown in the first screenshot.

How it is displayed currently:
[image]

How I would like it displayed:
[image]

My code:

```
<li style="display:%%GLOBAL_HideCartOptions%%">
    <span><a href="%%GLOBAL_ShopPathNormal%%/cart.php" title="%%LNG_ViewCart%%"><i class="icon-large sprite-glyphicons_halflings_115_shopping-cart2x icon-2x" style="position: relative; top: 14px; right: 20px;"></i><span class="badge badge-info" style="position: relative; top: 18px; right: 13px;">%%GLOBAL_CartItems%%</span></a></span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<li style="display:%%GLOBAL_HideCartOptions%%">
    <span><a href="%%GLOBAL_ShopPathNormal%%/cart.php" title="%%LNG_ViewCart%%"><i class="icon-large sprite-glyphicons_halflings_115_shopping-cart2x icon-2x" style="position: relative; top: 14px; right: 20px;"></i><span id='cart-items' class="badge badge-info" style="position: relative; top: 18px; right: 13px;">%%GLOBAL_CartItems%%</span></a></span>
</li>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var $cart_items = $('#cart-items');
$cart_items.text($cart_items.text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
</script>
```

This should work, but from an idealist perspective it's a dirty hack.  This assumes inclusion of jQuery.  The first thing I did was to give the container an ID... "cart-items".  The javascript then selects that element by ID and removes all non-numeric characters inside of it.

Comment: No way! Dirty or not, I can't believe this is finally working! I've been going at it for a week and a half...thank you sooooooo much! If I could I'd buy you a drink! Really appreciate your help! :-D

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the script above doesn't accommodate for displaying `(0)` when there are no items in the cart.

I came across the same issue, where BigCommerce's `%%GLOBAL_CartItems%%` variable adds `item` after the amount of items in the user's cart.

The script below to removes `items` from after the number of items in the cart provided by `%%GLOBAL_CartItems%%`, and if there are no items when the variable would not return anything, to add `(0)`.

```html
var num = $('#cartnumber').text().replace(/\D/g, '');
$('#cartnumber').text('( ' + num + ' )');

if ($('#cartnumber').text() == '(  )') {
    $('#cartnumber').text('(0)');
}
```